# Google Maps API - Get n closest markers from location

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've created a Google Map using the Maps API and now I would like to find the closest `n` markers to a given location. I found [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReneKorss/6DCTp/) which shows how to find the single closest marker, how can I adapt it so that it finds the closest `n` markers rather than just the single closest?

```
function find_closest_marker(event) {
    var distances = [];
    var closest = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var d = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markers[i].position, event.latLng);
        distances[i] = d;
        if (closest == -1 || d < distances[closest]) {
            closest = i;
        }
    }
    console.log('Closest marker is: ' + markers[closest].getTitle());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution ever, but assuming the original source code, should be able to do the job.

```
function find_closest_markers(event, n) {
    var markers_distances = [];
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var d = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markers[i].position, event.latLng);
        markers_distances[i] = {
            distance: d, 
            marker: markers[i]
        }
    }
    var closest_markers = markers_distances.sort((a, b) => {return a.distance-b.distance}).slice(0,n)
    return closest_markers.map((item) => {return item.marker})
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this seems to return all of my markers, regardless of the number I pass into the function as `n`.

Comment: Changed the solution, can you please try it like this? Works fine for my mock object.

Comment: Yep, adding the `0,` into the `slice` seemed to resolve the issue. Thanks!